# Web service java

Tags: java, web-services, jsp

Good morning,
I want to create a java Web service able to change the status displayed in a jsp Web application (from Start to Stop). 
The call of this Web service is done from another jsp Web application by pressing a trigger button.
[image]

I don't know how to do this, or where to start. I'm counting on your help and direction.
Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create web services using jersey or spring boot,from jsp you can call easily using ajax calls.